# JavaFx Project working in netbeans but not running from dist or cmd

Tags: java, git, javafx, netbeans, derby

sorry in advance if this is not in the right place or if im not asking properly but im still trying to get to grips with stackoverflow and the correct way to ask questions.

I have been looking for 2 years for a great javafx tutorial and finally committed the time to going through all the videos but...

When i got to the last video and tried to run the jar from the dist folder nothing happens? there are no errors coming from netbeans and the project works great within the netbeans ide but as soon as i try to run the jar from the dist folder nothing happens and if run from the cmd nothing happens.

In task manager it shows for a split second but then disappears.

I have attached a zip file to git if anyone could take a look and let me know either what is wrong or point me in the right direction of what I could be doing wrong.

Many apologies in advance but im extremely new to javafx and not quite sure how to tackle the problem

https://github.com/castorTroyUK/JavaFx-Library-Assistant-Tutorial-Error-Finding/blob/master/LibraryAssistant.zip

EDIT:  I have tried this on another computer now and it runs but.... there seams to be a problem with the alerts and database updates, seams laggy etc but lists work fine? any ideas?

but runs super quick in netbeans?

Comment: You need to export the project into a runnable JAR, not a normal JAR. If you want to run using the same JAR file, you probably need to go to command line and use `java -jar foobar.jar`.

Comment: Hi there I tried that but comes up with the following error.. Error: unable to access jarfile Library

Comment: i have run, please give a user name and password if possible

Comment: hi there its admin admin, may i ask how you got it to run as all i can get it to do is run in netbeans?

Comment: You need to learn enough about the program you are trying to run to figure out where the actual error message is going, so that you can say something more precise and specific than: "there seems to be a problem with the alerts and database updates". To make progress, you have to find the **actual** error. Then post those details to your question.